# How to retrieve result data foreach in foreach on cakephp

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I like to produce some universal function for my project
in a harcode php mode it would be like :

```
    <select id="segment" name="segment">
        <option value=''></option>
            <?php
            $sql = "select segment_id, segment_name, segment_parentid 
from test_segment where segment_parentid = 'root' and segment_status = '1'  order by segment_name asc";

            $sql  = $koneksi_db->sql_query($sql);
            while($row = $koneksi_db->sql_fetchrow($sql)){
                printf( "<option value=$row[segment_id] disabled>".ucwords($row['segment_name'])."</option>" );
                $sql1 = "select segment_id, segment_name, segment_parentid from test_segment where  convert(varchar, segment_id) <> 'root' and
                segment_parentid= '$row[segment_id]' and segment_status = '1' order by segment_name asc";

                $sql1  = $koneksi_db->sql_query($sql1);
                while($row1 = $koneksi_db->sql_fetchrow($sql1)){
                    printf( "<option value=$row1[segment_id]>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|_".ucwords($row1['segment_name'])."</option>" );
                }
            }
            ?>
        </select>
```

How to convert that code into cakephp MVC method code? the Controller and Model
, I shall not to breaking MVC method with hardcode way for this code.

note : $koneksi_db->sql_query, $koneksi_db->sql_fetchrow was my own function for query process, and for query I cannot change into cakephp method, because it was restrict procedure from my mentor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to create a model representing the dataset you want.  Then load the model for any controller that needs access to the data and that controller's view using that data in the in the select.

Step1:  Create a MySQL view to represent the two SQL statements:

```
CREATE VIEW segments AS
SELECT segment_id, UPPER(segment_name), segment_parentid, UPPER(segment_name) AS sortfield
FROM test_segment
WHERE segment_parentid = 'root' AND segment_status = '1'
UNION
SELECT UPPER(test_segment.segment_id), test_segment.segment_name, test_segment.segment_parentid, UPPER(CONCAT(parent.segment_name, test_segment.segment_name))
FROM test_segment
JOIN test_segment AS parent
ON test_segment.segment_parentid = parent.segment_id
AND parent.segment_status = '1'
WHERE convert(varchar, test_segment.segment_id) <> 'root' 
AND test_segment.segment_status = '1';
```

Step2: Create Model for this

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class Segment extends AppModel {

    // the name of the view
    public $useTable = 'segment';
    public $displayField = 'segment_name';
    public $primaryKey = 'segment_id';
}
```

Step3: In whatever controller method you want this, Use this code

```
$this->loadModel('Segment');
$segments = $this->Segment->find('list', array('order => array('sortfield')));
set('segments', $segments);
```

Step4: Then in that controller's view, add the element (I'm assuming you will use the form helper, otherwise you can write the html out:

```
echo $this->Form->select('segments',$segments);
```

Comment: It was a great idea to create sql view on my database
and call it in to my model
great help, thx.